# How make scrollbar appear in Window with Panel with undefined size?

Tags: scrollbar, vaadin, panel

In the example bellow - window with Panel grows till it reaches browser window limits.
After that Panel content becomes scrollable but no scrollbar appear.
If I set Panel to fixed size scrollbar appear as per documentation.

Can someone suggest Vaadin pattern to implement scrollbars when Window or Panel size reaches browser window limit?

```
public class DemoUI extends UI {

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    layout.setSizeFull();
    Button demo1 = new Button("Question");
    demo1.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent clickEvent) {
            Window window = new Window();
            window.setClosable(true);
            window.center();
            window.setResizable(true);
            window.setModal(false);
            window.setContent(new UndefWindow(window));

            addWindow(window);
        }
    });
    layout.addComponent(demo1);
    setContent(layout);
}
}

public class UndefWindow extends VerticalLayout {

private Window window;
public UndefWindow(Window window){
    this.window = window;
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    Button add10 =new Button("Add 10");
    add10.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent clickEvent) {
            for (int i=0; i <10; i++){
                layout.addComponent(new Label("Label: "+i));
            }
            window.center();
        }
    });
    layout.addComponent(add10);
    panel.setContent(layout);
    addComponent(panel);
    setExpandRatio(panel, 1.0f);

}
}
```

**EDIT: I was able to achieve this with SizeReporter addon - code bellow**

[SizeReporter](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/sizereporter)

```
public class UndefWindow extends VerticalLayout {

private Window window;
VerticalLayout root;
int rootHeight;
public UndefWindow(Window window, VerticalLayout root){
    this.window = window;
    this.root = root;

    Panel panel = new Panel();
 //   panel.setHeight("400px");

    SizeReporter sizeReporterRoot = new SizeReporter(root);
    sizeReporterRoot.addResizeListener(new ComponentResizeListener() {
        @Override
        public void sizeChanged(ComponentResizeEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Root size: " + event.getWidth() + " x " + event.getHeight());
            rootHeight = event.getHeight();
        }
    });
    SizeReporter sizeReporter = new SizeReporter(panel);
    sizeReporter.addResizeListener(new ComponentResizeListener() {
        @Override
        public void sizeChanged(ComponentResizeEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Panel size: " + event.getWidth() + " x " + event.getHeight());
            if(event.getHeight()>rootHeight){
                window.setHeight(rootHeight-60, Unit.PIXELS);
                //window.center();
                panel.setHeight(rootHeight-60, Unit.PIXELS);
            }else
                window.center();
        }
    });

    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

    Button add10 =new Button("Add 10");
    add10.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent clickEvent) {
            for (int i=0; i <10; i++){
                layout.addComponent(new Label("Label: "+i));
            }
        }
    });
    addComponent(add10);
    panel.setContent(layout);
    addComponent(panel);

}
}
```

Comment: In your example, a scrollbar appears in the window https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JBYa.png

Comment: @Javier - what browser? It does not show-up in Chrome. Anyway - the solution I found works in Chrome.

Comment: Chrome & IE11. Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Here is screenshot. OSX, Crome. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ3TJ.png

Comment: Which Vaadin version?

Comment: @Javier Vaadin 8.3.3

Comment: I recompiled the theme and tried with Vaadin 8.3.3 but could not reproduce the issue. Please check whether https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/10828 applies to your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bit overly complicated thinking in your Window content. In Vaadin, Window itself extends Panel, so you do not need additional Panel there at all. So I stripped it away. Also in order to layouts to work properly, you want to have your VerticalLayout height undefined, i.e. to grow until browser window size is met. In order to Panel scrolling to work in that scenario, there needs to be some content of defined height, in this case it is the Label, so I set defined height to Label. Then adding labels, will add size of the VerticalLayout, and once browser height is exceeded, Panel gets scroll bars.

```
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setSizeFull();
        Button demo1 = new Button("Question");
        demo1.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent clickEvent) {
                Window window = new Window("Window");
                window.setClosable(true);
                window.center();
                window.setResizable(true);
                window.setModal(false);
                window.setContent(new UndefWindow(window));

                addWindow(window);
            }
        });
        layout.addComponent(demo1);
        setContent(layout);
    }

    public class UndefWindow extends VerticalLayout {
        private Window window;
        public UndefWindow(Window window){
            this.window = window;
            Button add10 =new Button("Add 10");
            add10.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent clickEvent) {
                    for (int i=0; i <10; i++){
                        Label label = new Label("Label: "+i);
                        label.setHeight("38px");    
                        addComponent(label);
                    }
                    window.center();
                }
            });
            addComponent(add10);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Chrome 65.0.3325.181 OSX 10.11.6 No ScrollBars. Firefox 59.0.2 - Got scrollbar. Safari 11.0.2 - No scrollbar (Also Safari doesn't show srollbar even when I set Panel size)

Comment: Content however is scrollable is either case with Panel or without. It does looks like a bug similar to one mentioned by @Javier

Comment: @Crypto I had scrollbar with Chrome 65 / Windows 10. But I have seen odd scroll bar behavior with OSX and Chrome before.